# Automated digitization within a point layer in QField

Tags: point, elevation, contour, qfield, inverse-distance-weighted

I am attempting to create elevation contour lines for a piece of property with the help of a GNSS sensor hooked up to a tablet with QField installed. So far, it looks like the screenshot below. I used the IDW-Interpolation algorithm but the results are, I believe, pretty inaccurate due to the low number of measuring points. [image: Measuring points displaying absolute elevation with an IDW-Interpolation algorithm applied.]

Afterwards, I vectorized the interpolation using raster-to-vector conversion to create elevation contour lines as shown below. [image: Contour lines]

Now as you can see the contour lines are pretty wobbly and don't reflect the actual terrain. A denser net of measuring points would help, I believe, but adding these point objects by hand would be pretty tedious, so I'm wondering if I could somehow automate that process in a way that QField creates a measurement point every .5 seconds while I walk around the property?

I already found a tracking feature in the QField documentation, however I believe that it just creates vertices on a line in a fixed interval and not point objects measuring elevation. You can find a description of that tracking feature here: https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/tracking/

I'd be happy for any advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial of Ujaval Gandhi
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html

Comment: That's a great tutorial. Thanks for posting! Unfortunately, I don't think it is useful for my problem as my initial question was how to automate the elevation measuring process.